# Representation Theory group element as a vector

Tags: representation-theory

This is a very introductory level question.  I am reading "The Symmetric Group" by Bruce Sagan and I am stuck on a concept.

In Example 1.3.4 he talks about the regular representation of the cyclic group $C_4$ and provides the standard basis $g^{2}\textbf{e}=\textbf{g}^2$, $g^{2}\textbf{g}=\textbf{g}^3$, $g^{2}\textbf{g}^2=\textbf{e}$ and $g^2\textbf{g}^3=\textbf{g}$ where $g \in C_4$, $e$ is the identity and bold symbols correspond to vectors.

Here is what I am stuck on.  I understand $g$ as a permutation but I don't know how to picture the equivalent vector $\textbf{g}$.

Answer (score 0):

It can be confusing to think of the group element $g$ and the vector $\mathbf{g}$ as the ``same thing.'' If you like, choose a basis $v_0, v_1, v_2, v_3$ which span a representation determined by $g v_0 = v_1, g^2 v_0 = v_2, g^3 v_0 = v_3$, etc.

Here is one perspective that may be confusing now, but will be useful if you continue on in representation theory. If you view the underlying vector space of the regular representation as functions from $G = C_4$ to $\mathbb{C}$ (i.e. just an assignment of a number to each group element), then $G$ acts on the space of functions on itself by right translation: $g \cdot f(x) = f(x g)$. This is the regular representation, and you can view $\mathbf{g}$ as the function taking the value $1$ at $g$ and $0$ at all the other elements (the ``delta function at $g$'').